# How to hide title on chart?

Tags: c#, charts

In my project I use MS Charts and I would like to show/hide these titles programmatically 
[image]

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to hide it

`Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.Title = ""`